# Camel: detect Kafka wrong IP

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka

I am configuring Kafka as a source in my RouteBuilder. My goal is to handle Kafka disconnection issues. My RouteBuilder is as follows:

```
new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            onException(Exception.class).process(exchange -> {
                final Exception exception = exchange.getException();
                logger.error(exception.getMessage());
                // will do more processing here
            });
            from(String.format("kafka:%s?brokers=%s:%s", topicName, host, port)).bean(getMyService(), "myMethod")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // some more processing
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

I provided wrong host and port, and expected to see an exception. However, no exception is seen in the log, and the onException processing is not get called.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

A similar problem can be reproduced by running https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/kafka/MessageConsumerClient.java locally without any Kafka server running. Doing so results in a constant flow of messages:

```
Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Is there a way to have an exception thrown? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OnException in the RouteBuilder will be triggered when you have a message to route, but since you are unable to connect to Kafka cluster you don't have that. That's why you don't see exception handled.

Comment: But how can I detect that I have no connection?

Comment: Maybe you can use a producer and try to send something to Kafka first.

Comment: I made some progress and learned that I need to use setBridgeErrorHandler on the end point (see http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.0/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultEndpoint.html#setBridgeErrorHandler-boolean-) 
 have modified the 
example - 

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/kafka/MessageConsumerClient.java
and 
added following code right after camelContext.start():

Comment: final Collection<Endpoint> endpoints = camelContext.getEndpoints(); 
        for (Endpoint endpoint : endpoints) { 
                final DefaultEndpoint endpoint1 = (DefaultEndpoint) 
endpoint; 
                endpoint1.setBridgeErrorHandler(true); 
                final HashMap<String, Object> consumerProperties = new 
HashMap<>(); 
                consumerProperties.put("backoffMultiplier", 10); 
                consumerProperties.put("backoffErrorThreshold", 5); 
                endpoint1.setConsumerProperties(consumerProperties); 
        }

Comment: I ran the main() and hoped to see the consumer stopping the attempts to 
connect to Kafka after 5 tries, but this did not work. I keep getting 
output messages of “Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker 
may not be available.” 

Is this the right way to go? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a good example how tricky Apache Camel is. I'm working on a project having Apache Camel Kafka and I see how badly this is designed. Every Kafka parameter has corresponding Camel URL query-parameter. What if Kafka introduces a new configuration parameter and Apache Camel is not updated to get a new query-parameter? Then there is no way to use this Kafka parameter at all! It's insane.

Example of such Kafka configuration parameter is `client.dns.lookup` (I need to set it to *'use_all_dns_ips'*) introduced in Kafka 2.1. No Apache Camel URL query-param to set this!

**SOLUTION:** Replace Apache Camel Kafka by Spring Kafka.